# Sidebar for Google App Script doesn't show content in Chrome

Tags: google-apps-script

I didn't manage to show content on sidebar with Google App Script until I understood it wasn't working only for Chrome / OS 10.11.6...

This script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs
doesn't work on Chrome 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit), it is working well on safari.

Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new doc and ran the quickstart without issue.
Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m

There is a broken link for an icon on the bottom of the sidebar. But the rest renders in chrome.

Check on both windows and osx. Both work.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer! Here is the result I have: https://infinit.io/_/kdkSeZF in chrome and: https://infinit.io/_/a83rLse in Safari, do you have an idea what I should have done wrong?

Comment: I have updated the question: it is working for PC... You have a PC right? :)

Comment: I checked on both windows 7 and osx 10.11.6

Comment: Thanks, your comment, it makes me dig deeper... it seems it is working in private mode. It is working on an other MAC computer. Butit doesn't work for two different user on the same computer/chrome/OSX... So I deleted all the cookies, the cache but it still doesn't work... An other idea?